# Physical Limits on HVDC Voltage

Tags: voltage, power-engineering, hvdc

Higher Voltage minimizes I^2*R losses in power lines - we have power lines up to 1 megavolt, and presumably going any higher in terms of voltage doesn't save you too much power.

But say we do something like build a ton of solar panels in the Sahara and need to deliver a TW of electrical power to Europe or China (ignore the engineering nightmare that this would impose on the current electrical grids, just consider the geographic distance). Doing this with a mere megavolt would require a mega-amp of current, and the losses would be hideous.

What's the highest we can go in terms of voltage? What factors limit you from going higher?

Comment: It's a ridiculous scenario to begin with. A project of that scale would be done in space, not on the surface, and the power would be delivered as relatively broad beams of microwaves. You'd never have the entire TW flowing through any single point of the network. And if you did need to transfer that amount of power terrestrially, you'd be using superconductors.

Comment: No need to cross the waters. The deserts of Spain would do fine. As would many a rocky Greek Island. USA needs about 40by40 mile region, if I recall the math rightly.

Comment: In all honesty, I think corona discharge and vandalism are the limiting factors. You can separate the wires and insulate them all you want, but humans will be humans. - A more realistic approach would be if everyone had solar panels in their countries and then gave away/sold power to other countries that are in their night time. The earth is round after all.

Comment: Vandals will likely only do it once...

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be a 3200 or 3400km 1.1MV link (??? +/- 1.1 MV?) capable of carrying 12GW, in China, recently commissioned. Mentioned on [this Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-high-voltage_electricity_transmission_in_China?fbclid=IwAR0o9XFZsbHcYo0ArAjRGEywVvGKS92wpFoPkdfXU80th18NYlfpVuLB0e4) : scroll down to Zhundong-Wannan.

This is a significant distance because it could (*just* : Shannon to Gander) span the Atlantic, or potentially carry near-peak generation from one timezone to cover peak consumption in another, which might prove at least as lucrative as a north-south link carrying power from a sunny climate to a cloudier one.

[The first graph on this page](https://new.abb.com/systems/hvdc/why-hvdc/economic-and-environmental-advantages) suggests that a +/-400kv DC link carrying 1.2 GW could operate around 90% efficiency up to 1500 km, so 80% for a larger capacity 3000km link would seem conservative.

Press release on one of the "transformers" used [here.](https://press.siemens.com/global/en/feature/worlds-first-1100-kv-hvdc-transformer?fbclid=IwAR2aaavVsjZ7Lf4bGScO44FIY7-jMu2qEBTZtlNE8bTx6SfGUjA8u02FvAk)

To carry 1 TW, you would need 80 of these links, or perhaps, fewer of whatever comes next.

Answer (score 1):

Summary:

- Voltages not vastly about present maximum are liable to be the sensible limit.
- While energy losses are large in absolute terms, they are still small as a percentage and compared to those at under say 100 kV.

---

Space origination of energy was mentioned  - but a solar PV system **IS** a space energy based system - trading orbital collector efficiency gains against the rather non-trivial advantage of not having to place ANYTHING in orbit.

The large orbital rectenna systems of the 1950s and 60s seem to have quietly faded from mention. Somewhat higher conversion efficiencies due to eg the use of triple junction cells able to convert the short wavelength US (not available at the earth's surface) and increased IR energy are offset by the sheer scale of putting this amount of equipment into orbit and maintaining it and the provision and operation of the required ground energy receivers. Continually falling PV system costs help the case for land based systems. Space based systems are liable to provide energy for a larger percentage of a day, but probably not '24/7' as geostationary distances are unattractive, and filling the geosynchronous orbit with power stations is 'liable to be frowned on'.

Without revisiting the claims for these space based system I'd suspect that they would be unable to compete with modern ground based PV systems.

Good 2012 paper commenting on cost issues and site selection
[Global High-Power Rectenna Site Selection](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3914/53060eca99aecd6a742f10c4da7be0168954.pdf)

Oleg Nizhnik, Department of JST, ERATO Human-Sensing Fusion Project,
Open Labs Bld., 8111, Shosha 2167, Himeji-shi, Hyogo-ken, Japan

**Solar PV 1 TW - what do we need?**

Assumptions are stated below.
Adjust assumptions to suit.

The scale is such that very large physical separations exist between the various likely concentration points. Assuming say 200 W/m<sup>2</sup> module deleivered to grid (high by current standards) and a say 25% area utilisation gives 50 W/m<sup>2</sup> effective. So 10<sup>12</sup> watts requires
10<sup>12</sup>/50 = 2 × 10<sup>10</sup> m<sup>2</sup>
= 2 × 10<sup>4</sup> km<sup>2</sup>
= about 200 x 100 km.

10<sup>12</sup> watt is about 3 x the installed worldwide nuclear capacity - with an average reactor providing approaching 1000 MW and combinations of reactors seldom exceeding 5000 MW.

If power capacity per major node or station was set at 5000 MW then 200 "stations" are required with a collection are of around 2 × 10<sup>4</sup>/200 or 100 km<sup>2</sup> per 5000 MW station.
This is geographically large enough that treating the system as 200 x 5000 MW power stations with their own switch gear, transmission lines etc "probably makes sense".

The [Ekibastuz-Kokshetau](https://wiki2.org/en/Powerline_Ekibastuz-Kokshetau) system mentioned below uses 50 tons of conductors between pylons!

The largest nuclear plant in the world is Bruce at around 6000 MW.

The highest power transmission lines are around 5000 - 6000 MW, typically at around +/- 50-0 kV DC or 1 MV AC. 
"Somewhat larger" than these values will no doubt occur as technology advances, but the capacity of a given system is liable to be well below 1 TW for 'some while yet'.

---

DC links are usually used for under-water or under-ground systems due to impedance issues.

The 560 MW Inga-Shaba HVDC line is 1700 km long and operates at around +/- 500 kVDC relative to ground.

The Brazilian Iatapu +/- 600 kV DC 6300 MW transmission line is 780 km long.

[Kazakhstans Ekibastuz-Kokshetau](https://wiki2.org/en/Powerline_Ekibastuz-Kokshetau) AC 1150 kV 5500 MW 430 km.

Wikipedia [Overhead power line](https://wiki2.org/en/Overhead_power_line) - useful

Wikipedia [Electric Power Transmission](https://wiki2.org/en/Electric_power_transmission) - useful'

[Inga Shaba HVDC](https://wiki2.org/en/Inga-Shaba)

[Itaipu HC DC](https://wiki2.org/en/HVDC_Itaipu)

[Ekibastuz–Kokshetau HV AC](https://wiki2.org/en/Powerline_Ekibastuz-Kokshetau)

Comment: Tip of the day, Russell. You can also use HTML `&Omega;`, `&mu;`, `&deg;`, `&times;`, etc. as well as `<sup>...</sup>` and `<sub>...</sub>` in the posts (but they don't work in the comments). I've edited them in for you. Please have a look at your paragraph about Bruce. I think there's a typo in '50-0 kV'.